# YUI autocomplete misalignment problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, yui

[image]

I am using the autocomplete YUI feature. However, as you can see I am having trouble aligning  the suggestion drop down with the text input when I put a label in front of the text input. I am following [the example here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_basic_array_clean.html) exactly except for this snippet of code where I simply replace the H3 with a label element in the form:

```
<div id="myAutoComplete">
<label>Enter a state:</label>
    <input id="myInput" type="text">
    <div id="myContainer"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/assets/js/data.js"></script>
```

(I also had to change the  data.js path from a relative to absolute path.)

What is the best way to have the suggestion drop down to line up with the text input? I would like a solution that works on all popular modern browsers (FF3, Safari, Chrome, IE), plus IE6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AutoComplete doesn't automatically brute-force the position of your AC container every time it shows, because unless you're doing inline work this is unnecessary.  However, now that you've moved your input field inline, you do need to take another step to align the container, either with custom CSS or brute force JS positioning.

Here's the brute force approach.

After you define your AC instance:

```
oAC.doBeforeExpandContainer = function() {
    var Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom;
    Dom.setXY("myContainer", [Dom.getX("myInput"), Dom.getY("myInput") + Dom.get("myInput").offsetHeight] );
    return true;
}
```

Here's a working example:

http://ericmiraglia.com/yui/demos/acalign.php

Comment: Eric you are awesome. Thanks, that worked great. Out of curiosity why do you say "brute force"? Is it burdensome on the browser, somehow?

Comment: Julien, It's brute force in the sense that CSS can take care of it for you in most cases. As for the docs, there are a few examples that show this (see the centering example, for instance), but I agree that this is the kind of nuance that's hard to document well (and we could do a better job of it).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this auto-complete plugin isn't using the infamous [element position](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) technique by quirksmode to find the *real* position of an element on the page.

Does the label need to be inline with the input box? You could very well fix this by either puttint a `<br>` after the `label`, or by actually setting a `margin-left` on the `<div id="myContainer">` element.

Otherwise you should probably file this as a bug, and tell them to use quirksmode way of doing this (it's cross-browser).

Comment: Thanks Luca. Yes, I would like to inline the label and have the text input and suggestion drop down line up to the right of the label.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, just a simple customization needed for specific design.

In case you are not using url's to add those js files, you just need to find the js code that generate table/div which populates your results. Code would be either generating whole table on fly, or would be setting an already hidden table/div 's visibility to 'visible'.
If you find that code, you would just need to add an attribute to set its left position to match its 'px' position with you textbox.

Or else find what css class is being applied to that container of result, and try setting it left and absolute position.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem...

I wanted an inline YUI autocomplete so that i would place a label then a textbox with autocomplete without a line break. And i've found an answer: http://starikovs.com/2009/11/04/inline-yui-autocomplete-layout/. It's a CSS solution, there's no JavaScript.